# How can I overcome the property length limitation of the "adb shell setprop"

Tags: android, properties

I get an error when I try set a value for property with name >= 32 characters

```
adb shell setprop 01234567890123456789012345678901 VALUE
```

Error:

```
could not set property
```

This works fine

```
adb shell setprop 0123456789012345678901234567890 VALUE
adb shell getprop 0123456789012345678901234567890
VALUE
```

Is there any way to set properties with longer names?

Answer (score 12):

It looks like there would be no way to bypass this limitation. I see the same rules in android java sources.

```
public class SystemProperties
{
    public static final int PROP_NAME_MAX = 31;
    public static final int PROP_VALUE_MAX = 91;

    ...
}
```

Comment: [sigh] yes, the Android OS likes putting random limitations without a good enough reason.

Comment: Inside the C code from the Android NDK used internally by the Java VM on Android you can find this in the usr/include/sys/system_properties.h header: https://gist.github.com/mnemonicflow/6c689f30899a654867b3#file-system_properties-h-L38 `#define PROP_NAME_MAX   32
#define PROP_VALUE_MAX  92` In C the additional byte is used to termine the string with a '\0'

Answer (score 3):

Update: The system property name limit of 32 characters was removed in Android O. You are free to have longer names now.

```
public class SystemProperties {
    /**
     * Android O removed the property name length limit, but com.amazon.kindle 7.8.1.5
     * uses reflection to read this whenever text is selected (http://b/36095274).
     */
    public static final int PROP_NAME_MAX = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    public static final int PROP_VALUE_MAX = 91;
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I also faced same problem. as the answer mentioned above it's not possible use the NAME which longer than 31.
so i change package name to shorter than 31 and it works now.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe using redirection?

Set small property which will hold file name for conf file:

```
setprop confFileName "myConf.yml"
```

in that conf file have all your big property names and values.