# How do I run valgrind with an Android app?

Tags: android, android-ndk, valgrind

I've installed valgrind for android and I can confirm it is working as I tried running ls with it, and it works fine.

But how do I execute an android app with a native component I would like to debug? I looked at this question: [How to start an android app with valgrind](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9123124/how-to-start-an-android-app-with-valgrind) but I have no idea how to follow it. How do you wrap an app in a shell script? What is "wrap." followed by the package name supposed to be?

I tried doing this with com.matthewmitchell.wakeifyplus being my application package:

```
setprop wrap.com.matthewmitchell.wakeifyplus "logwrapper /data/local/valgrind"
```

but it says "could not set property". What am I supposed to do? I can't find any step by step guide that works. I did try this (I don't even know what setprop does):

```
setprop com.matthewmitchell.wakeifyplus "logwrapper /data/local/valgrind"
```

With /data/local/valgrind being a shell script with execute permissions which is:

```
#!/system/bin/sh
VGPARAMS='--error-limit=no'
export TMPDIR=/data/data/com.matthewmitchell.wakeifyplus
exec /data/local/Inst/bin/valgrind $VGPARAMS $*
```

But when I run the app with:

```
am start -a android.intent.action.MAIN -n com.matthewmitchell.wakeifyplus/.MainActivity
```

valgrind does not show up in logcat, even after clearing it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You get the error "**could not set property**" because **you CANNOT set a property name with a length greater than 31**, which is the number maximum allowed characters in the property name: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5068818/313113

Try to reduce the package name length to less than or equal 31 characters when you set the property with adb shell setprop.
And use a bash script to simply things.
For further details see my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19235439/313113

Comment: and what happens in the cases that we want to run it on an application that does not belong to us? anyway to workaround the 31 chars limitation

Comment: On my machine it produces another error: `usage: setprop <key> <value>`
I guess this is because token `"logwrapper /data/local/valgrind"`. But when I escape this space character, it still does not work.