# How I pass the property length limitation in “adb shell setprop”

Tags: android, system

when I tried to Set system property for andriod 6.00 I got this message. I know that is not accept more than 32 characters but I need to bypass this limitation. My experiment should take any length of app name.

```
     $ setprop com.example.shalidalkhaffabi.headerparser LD_PRELOAD=/data/local/tmp/libpreload.so
```

After I press Enter I got :

```
      setprop: name 'com.example.shalidalkhaffabi.headerparser' too long; try 'com.example.shalidalkhaffabi.he'
```

Any Idea?

Answer (score -3):

Duplicate of [How can I overcome the property length limitation of the "adb shell setprop"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5068305/how-can-i-overcome-the-property-length-limitation-of-the-adb-shell-setprop).

Short answer: Prior to Android O, you can't. The limit was removed in Android O.

Comment: Please don't use answers to mark duplicates. Instead, please use `Flag > duplicate of...`

Comment: I do not see a "flag > duplicate of..." option. When I click on flag, my only options are spam, abuse, and needs moderator attention. If there was a "mark as duplicate" option anywhere, I would have done that.

Comment: @JeremyFrank if you did that now, it's because it was closed 22 hours ago. You can't flag a question as a duplicate (closing) if it's already closed.